# Angular - How to wait for provider get request to finish before loading components?

Tags: javascript, angular

My program using a global variable used in my player.ts file. I imported this player file into the sidebar component and now app errors. The problem is that the app is loading the sidebar component before the get request is finished in the player.ts. I am Initialing the player.ts file first in my app.module. If there away I can prompt app to wait before loading the components? I tried using the await javascript keyword but all the components and imported files are being loaded asynchronous from app.moudle it seems.

app.moudle.ts

```
 import { Player } from './player';
 import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     SidebarComponent,
   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     HttpClientModule,
        ],
   providers: [Player],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

 export class AppModule {

   constructor(private player: Player) { 
     console.log("first console.log yeee");
     this.processPlayer()
   }
   async processPlayer(){
     let tester1 = await this.player.loadPlayer();
   }
  }
```

sidebar.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { Player } from '../player';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-sidebar',
   templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
 })
 export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
   projects
   focussections
   constructor(private router: Router, private player: Player) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     //get all the project to list on sidebar
     this.projects = this.player.getAllProjects();
     this.focussections = this.player.getAllSections4Project(this.focusID);
   }

   navigate2CreateTaskQuicky(){
     let info = {typeID:0}
     this.router.navigate(['/createtask', JSON.stringify(info)]);

   } 

 }
```

player.ts

```
 @Injectable()
 export class Player  {
    player : any
   constructor(private http: HttpClient)  {
     this.ngOnInit();
   }

   async ngOnInit() {}

    loadPlayer(){
     return this.http.get(url)
     .toPromise()
     .then(
       res => { // Success
         this.player = res;
         console.log("the player is fully loaded");
         console.log(this.player);
       }
     );
   }

   getAllProjects(){
     return this.player.projects;
   }

   getAllSections4Project(focusID){
     let inboxSectionStack = [];
     if(this.player){
       for(let x = 0; x< this.player.sections.length; x++){ 
         if(this.player.sections[x].project == focusID ){
           inboxSectionStack.push(this.player.sections[x]);
          }
       }// loop through all tasks in player
   }
   return inboxSectionStack;
   }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) provider. In this are services which are run before the `AppComponent` (and any other component) is rendered:

AppModule:

```
providers: [
  Player,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initApp,
    multi: true,
    deps: [ Player ]
  }
]
```

You can then make the factory. Make sure the factory returns a function which in turn returns a `Promise`:

```
export function initApp(player: Player) {
  return () => this.player.loadPlayer()
}
```

If you do not care that the AppComponent is rendered, but you do not want the route to be resolved yet, you can set the `initialNavigation` flag in the router config to false, and use a service inside the AppComponent to resolve and route to a correct path

Comment: Thanks a bunch, perfect fix. I am now aware of App_Initializer.

Comment: Hi a new issue is occurring now. I added another code for another variable to be updated in my ngOnInit() sidebar component. "this.focussections = this.player.getAllSections4Project(this.focusID);". Why is this new value not being updated real time. Ive tested the code some and it appears functions from my service with parameters dont update the view real time and require me to nav around and come back to page. Any insight to what might cause focussetion variable to not update live like the projects variable?